# How to unit test the Slider component in mui v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a unit test for a React component in which a Mui slider is used to select the quota. The slider is used as follows in that component.

```js
import { Slider } from '@mui/material';

<Slider
   data-testid="quota-slider"
   step={10}
   size="medium"
   min={10}
   onChange={(event: Event, value: number | number[]) => {
      setSliderValue(value)
   }
   value={sliderValue}
/>
```

I wrote a mock for this Slider component and tried to use it in my tests as follows.

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('@mui/material/Slider', () => (props: any) => {
  const { id, name, min, max, onChange, testid } = props;
  return (
    <input
      data-testid={testid}
      type="range"
      id={id}
      name={name}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
});


test("test quota selection", () => {
  render(<Component />)
  fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId('quota-slider'), {
      target: { value: 20 },
  });
})
```

But when I'm running this, I'm getting the following error.

> The given element does not have a value setter

Does anyone can help me to get this error sorted out? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fireEvent.change` API works with standard HTML elements where the value can be changed directly, like `<input />` or `<textarea />`, you're trying to use it with a custom component, which doesn't have a value property that can be directly modified.

In your mock, the `onChange` prop is just passing the value from the `event.target.value`, which would be the string representation of the slider's value. The real `Slider` component from Material UI doesn't just receive the new value, but an event and the new value. That's why your test is failing.

The `fireEvent.change` is trying to set a value on your mock slider that doesn't directly exist, because it's a custom component. You can fix it by creating a custom firing event that matches the Slider's API.

Also you should pass `data-testid` prop in your mock correctly. It was wrongly received as `testid` in your previous mock.

Here I have used `...rest` as the rest syntax to extract the remaining properties to the new object. This creates a synthetic event that triggers the change with a `null` event and a new value parsed from the string value of the range input.

Try this out -->

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('@mui/material/Slider', () => (props: any) => {
  const { onChange, `data-testid`: testId, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <input
      data-testid={testId}
      type="range"
      onChange={event => {
        onChange(null, parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
});

test('test quota selection', () => {
  render(<Component />);
  const slider = screen.getByTestId('quota-slider');
  slider.value = "30";
  fireEvent.change(slider);
});
```